# Django Rendering images in Email templates

Tags: django

I have created the email template as shown below

{% load staticfiles %}

```
<h1 style="color:red; background-image:url('../images/contact.jfif')">Welcome {{contact_name}}!</h1><br>
Your username is {{ contact_email }} and your content is {{ form_content }}.
<img src="{{ request.get_host }}{% static 'images/logo.png' %}" alt="ddddd" />
- xyz

</div>
```

But the image is not getting displayed in the email and showing error [image: not getting displayed in email]

Can anyone help me by providing the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving the images url as relative to your own website.
But then you are trying to fetch it on google with that relative url.

**It will definitely show the error** as image will not be found on their server.

> **Try giving absolute url for the image.**

I think it should work fine then.

Comment: Could you please  give me an example

Comment: You can try `background-image:url('http://www.example.com/images/contact.jfif')` Something like this.

Comment: I am doing it in localhost and it didn't work for me

Comment: Yeah it will not work for localhost. It will only work if the site is hosted. Coz once mail is sent the context of your site is lost right?